# Ошибка Field 'id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

При изучении Hibernate застрял в связке таблиц. Выходит ошибка при добавлении
`Entity`. Не создается `statement`. Описание ошибки:

> Field 'id' doesn't have a default value.

```
@Entity
public class groupStudent {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
private String name;
private String lastName;


@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="student_id")
private student s;

public student getS() {
return s;
}

public void setS(student s) {
this.s = s;
}

public String getLastName() {
return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getName() {

return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public long getId() {

return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
this.id = id;
}



}


@Entity
public class student {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String name;
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "s")
private groupStudent gs;

public groupStudent getGs() {
return en;
}

public void setGs(groupStudent gs) {
this.gs = gs;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public Long getId() {

return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
this.id = id;
}
}



public class ModelService{
@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;
List<EntityModel> model;


@Transactional
public void addMod(groupStudent model){
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(model);
}

@Transactional
public void adMod(student stu){
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(stu);
}







@Controller
public class MoiController {
@Autowired
ModelService service;
@RequestMapping(value = "/addmodel",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addMod(HttpServletRequest request){

groupStudentl model = new groupStudent();
student s= new student();

String name = request.getParameter("name");
String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");


model.setName(name);
model.setLastName(lastName);

service.addMod(model);

String stu = request.getParameter("student");

s.setId(1L);
s.setName(stu);

model.setS(s);

service.adMod(s);

return "res";

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка говорит о том, что при сохранении новой записи в БД не удается определить значение для поля `id` (поскольку оно не указано при вставке записи и не имеет стандартного значения, которое БД могла бы использовать).

Варианты решения проблемы:

1. Явно указывать значение поля `id` при каждой вставке записи.
2. Добавить свойство `auto increment` для колонки `id` в БД, например:

   `ALTER TABLE groupStudent CHANGE id id INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;`